# Pascal: how to declare number of dimensions of a dynamic array during runtime?

Tags: arrays, pascal

I know that setlength(array, a, b...) is for declaring the length of dynamic arrays and dimensions and it requires you to know the number of dimensions, so how do you declare n dimensions (n is a variable)?

Comment: Dynamic arrays don't support variable dimensions. A two dimensional dynamic array, for example, is declared as: `my_array: array of array of <some_type>;`. And there's no syntax to dynamically "parameterize" the numbe of `array of` items.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible to vary the nesting level of normal (dynamic) arrays runtime.

But have a look at COM arrays, the vararray functions in unit variants though, afaik it is possible with those, but that is a purely library construct.

An example is at http:///www.stack.nl/~marcov/phpser.zip  implementing a simple php array deserializer that decodes a nested structure.